# Flask Restplus base URL changed to /api but didn't give json data

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

Hello I'm trying using Flask Restplus, I changed the Base URL from '/' to '/api'.
When the base URL is '/' it give me the JSON data.
After I changed the base URL to '/api' it didn't give me the data, only give me the Flask-restplus API page.

**This is my code**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api

# change base url '/' to '/api' 
blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api/')
api = Api(blueprint,
            title="Enrollment API",
            version='v0.1',
            description='Enrollment API for CRUD operation'
        )
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)


@api.route('/api','/api/')
class GetAndPost(Resource):
    ''' Get All '''
    def get(self):
        return jsonify(User.objects.all())

    ''' POST '''
    def post(self):
        data        = api.payload
        user_id     = data['user_id']
        email       = data['email']
        first_name  = data['first_name']
        last_name   = data['last_name']
        password    = data['password']

        user = User(user_id=user_id, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save() 
        return jsonify(User.objects(user_id=user_id))
```

I would like to get all json data when accessing '/api'. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the code with this code

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api

blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/v1')
api = Api(blueprint,
            title="Enrollment API",
            version='v0.1',
            description='Enrollment API for CRUD operation'
        )
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

Now my api is working again via localhost:5000/v1/api